# If $f:[0,1]\to (0,1)$ is a continuous mapping then which are NOT correct?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f:[0,1]\to (0,1)$ is a continuous mapping then which are NOT correct?

- $F\subset [0,1]$ is a closed set implies that $f(F)$ is a closed set in $\Bbb R$.
- If $f(0)<f(1)$ then $f([0,1])$ must be equal  to $[f(0),f(1)]$.
- $\exists x$ such that $f(x)=x$.
- $f([0,1])\neq (0,1)$.

  1. is false as continuous functions don't take closed sets to closed sets.
  2. is false as $f$ is not monotonically increasing.

3.Let $h(x)=f(x)-x\implies h(0)=f(0)>0;h(1)=f(1)-1<0\implies h(k)=0$ for some $k$ .hence true

4.true since continuous image of a compact set must be compact.

hence the correct options are 1,2.

But the answer is given to be 2 only .Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Statement (1) is true, since any closed subset of $[0,1]$ is compact, and hence its image is also compact, and hence closed in $\mathbb{R}$.  Note that more generally you can't prove a statement like (1) is false by just saying "continuous functions don't take closed sets to closed sets": you need to actually find a counterexample satisfying all the assumptions of the statement.  In this case, no counterexample exists.

Comment: Thank you very much ;I understood it